# How to automate a Jenkins task using groovy script which runs on script console

Tags: groovy, jenkins, automated-tests

I have groovy script which runs on jenkins script console. My objective here is to automate the process which should run everyday.
Could you guys help me in achieving this task?

Comment: Explained what you have tried to reach your goal.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  While stackoverflow is intended for people to ask for help, it is expected that the user provides examples of what they have tried.  Not only does this show that you have put effort into solving the problem, but also clarifies the question for people who may want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can automate it, but you will need to install one of the below plugins:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin
- Scriptler plugin is another plugin.

Then,
- Create a Jenkins Job
- Add (system groovy build action or groovy post build action)
- Run and Test

I hope it helps.

Cheers